# Is Global variables travel from .bss to .data segment?

Tags: global-variables, microcontroller, avr, ram

In microcontrollers architecture : for SRAM memory segments :
as I know that the uninitialized Global variable is allocated in the .bss segment of the SRAM (and the initialized ones are allocated in the .data segment).

so, the Question: When updating the value of a Global variable during the Run time of the program,
Is the Global variable travel from .bss to .data segment ?

Answer (score 4):

No. The location of the variable is set by the compiler. It makes sure all references to the global (and static) variables point to the correct location.

The reason that there are two segments is that they are treated differently by the C runtime, a portion of code that is added by the compiler to your program and that runs before jumping to your code.

The variables that are initialized are in the data section. The C runtime has a function that copies the values from the end of the program code space to the SRAM for these variables. These are most often at the top of RAM.

The variables that are not initialized do not not need such values in the program code. Instead, the C runtime runs a function that initializes all these variables to 0. (Some C runtimes don't even do this. For these runtimes, the variable will have whatever value is already in SRAM when your program begins.) These variables usually occupy the RAM directly after the initialized variables.

The end of RAM is the stack, and the heap starts after the uninitialized globals. Often, there is no mechanism to prevent these from overwriting each other. This is the famous "Stack Overflow".